# Empty input counting as full

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a form and you get the percent of the form you've completed. The problem is on one of the inputs, I get a result even though its empty. I'm not sure how to fix this. Heres the code

```
countMissing();

function countMissing() {

  //Get total inputs
  console.log("Total inputs " + form.getElementsByTagName('input').length);
  //Divide by complete inputs out of 100% and get percent
  console.log("The percentage is " + 100 / form.getElementsByTagName('input').length + "%");

  var tot = 100 / form.getElementsByTagName('input').length + "%"

  //Check
  var cback=function(){
    bad=0;
    $('.form :text').each(function (i,e) {
      if ($.trim($(e).val()) == "") bad++;

      //Change width
      $('.top').css('width', bad + '%');

    });
    //Missing amount of fields
    if (bad > 0) $('.congrats').css("display", "block").text(100/bad + ' Completed ');
    else $('.congrats').hide();
  }
  $(document).delegate('.form :text','focus',cback);
  $(document).delegate('.form :text','keyup',cback);
}
```

And a link to the demo http://jsbin.com/xijemuli/2/edit Any ideas?

Comment: If you are going to use jQuery, then *use* it: `form.getElementsByTagName('input').length` should be `$('input').length`

Comment: If i use it that way the submit button also counts. @cale_b

Comment: @user3624247 Wouldn't it be better to give your input an `id`, then? `$(#id).length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIDDLE** : http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/3mH6w/3/

```
function count(){
   console.log("Total inputs " + $('.form :text').length);
//Divide by complete inputs out of 100% and get percent
console.log("The percentage is " + bad / $('.form :text').length + "%");

return 100-(bad / $('.form :text').length)*100 + "%"
}
```

**UPDATE :**

Another example with form of 10 inputs : http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/3mH6w/6/

Comment: What I was trying to do is as you enter more it goes higher, not lower. But when I divide I get small results

Comment: So see upate now (try fiddle mentionned at answer)

Comment: Alright. But its `0.50`, not `50`. Is there a way I can get solid numbers instead of decimals? I don't mind `33.333`, but I just want number in front of the decimal point

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify .value().length (not sure if it includes the brackets or not - from memory:

form.getElementsByTagName('input').value.length

Comment: Where would i use this thought?

Comment: put "var myinput = form.getElementsByTagName('input').value().length " on top and then just refer to myinput all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your code tried to kill my computer. Here is the approach I'd take:

```
$('form').on('input', function(e) {

  var $inputs = $(this).find('input'),
      $empties = $inputs.filter(function(){
        return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
      });

  $('.info').text($empties.length + ' of ' + $inputs.length + ' are empty!');

}).trigger('input');
```

along with a small demo: http://jsbin.com/gitef/4/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

There were several things going on with your code, but the primary problem you were having is calculating the percentage.

To find the percentage of form remaining, the math is:

```
(total_fields - empty_fields / total_fields)
```

After making that change (and a few others), your tested and working code is as follows:

```
countMissing();

function countMissing() {
    var i = $('input').not('[type="button"]').length;

    var cback=function(){
        bad=0;
        $('.form :text').each(function (i,e) {
            if ($.trim($(e).val()) === "") bad++;
            $('.top').css('width', bad + '%');
        });
    // Missing amount of fields
    if (bad > 0) {
        $('.congrats').css("display", "block").text(((i - bad)/ i) * 100 + ' Completed ');
    } else {
        $('.congrats').hide();
    }

    $(document).delegate('.form :text','focus',cback);
    $(document).delegate('.form :text','keyup',cback);
}
```

Comment: I don't get the percentage. Can you make maybe a fiddle?